# How do I use OPENMPI java bindings with eclipse on windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, openmpi

Eclipse has built-in OPENMPI support but that works only for C/C++ projects. Is there any easyway to use OPENMPI Java bindings through Eclipse on Windows ?

I did go through :-

http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=java

But when I run this command ( ./configure --enable-mpi-java ) in my JDK installation directory. I get a ./configure commmand not recognized error.

Comment: using native code in a managed code isn't very easy, I'm afraid there isn't a straight solution other than write native functions(in java) that call the native code

Comment: The command you cite is used to build Open MPI with Java support. It should be executed in the root of the Open MPI source tree, not in your JDK installation directory. You do not need to do so if you have the library installed from a package and it already includes the Java bindings (very unlikely though).